# JPA fetching too many entity class objects even when it is not rqquired

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I have been working on a Enquiry ( ticket raising ) application.
But the application performance is low.
Here i had **two requirements** (overview page,detail page) in my application.
Whenever we open the application it has to show open tickets(enquireis) currently assigned to that user in a overview page.
The overview page has pagination for 10 records.
Here each record has a link to look into its details ( detail page).
We are using JPA and wicket technologies.

Here whenever we open the application,
the overview page has to show few  fields data that have been mapped to few fields in five entity classes.
Here the  main entity class is Enquiry which has other entities mapped to it like User,
Company,
Dealer,
Issue,
EnquiryText.

So when i open my application it needs few fields data in all these entities.
But JPA is loading all fields in all entities that are mapped to Enquiry class.
The worst part is other entities in Enquiry entity also mapped to some other entities.

```
Select enquiry.,enquiry.user.*,enquiry.company.*,
      enquiry.issue.*,enquiry.dealer.*,enquiry.enquiryText.*     
from 
Enquiry enquiry
      where ( enquiry.* = input value, enquiry.issue.* = input value   )
```

*I also had other requirement that when i click on each record in overview page it should  fetch all the details of that record.
So it has to fetch all the entities in this case.*

```
Select enquiry  
from Enquiry enquiry 
where ( enquiry.* = input value, enquiry.issue.* = input value  )
```

**Is it possible for us to make our application to stop fetching all entities 
but fetch few entity fields in one requirement(while showing overview page)
 and to make it fetch all entity fields  in other requirement(when we click on each record i.e ticket) ?**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENQRY")
public class Enquiry extends AbstractEntity {
@Id
@Column(name = "CONT")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "EMAILADRADD")
private String emailAddresses = "";
@Column(name = "CONFIHME")
private String Comments = "";
@Column(name = "STCONT")
private DateTime lastStatusChangeOn = new DateTime();
@Column(name = "CLANGOPTR")
private String operatorLanguage;
@Column(name = "CLANGISS")
private String issuerLanguage;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USERLUPD")
private User lastUpdateByUser;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USERCREAT")
private User createdByUser;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USERISS")
private User issuer;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CMPY")
private Company company;


@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "enquiry", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Where(clause = "CTEXT = 'DIAGN'")
private List<EnquiryText> diagnosis;        
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "enquiry")
private List<EnquiryText> texts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single solution to this problem.. two that I have in mind are:

1. Create a db view and then map a custom entity to this view (remember  that views are readonly)
2. Create a DTO class and then make a `select new dtopackege.myDto(e.field, e.field1, e.field2, e.field3.subfield) from MyEntity e`

Your DTO must have a constructor capable of initialize all parameters passed by the query.

Then based on your requirement you can chose to invoke your custom methods or simply the hibernate plain ones that will fetch all properties.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and going through my question.Could you please tell me what does 'DTO' classs means here and how to configure it.Is it a new class that we have to create ?

Comment: You are welcome! Yes a DTO is a class 'POJO', a data transfer object, that you can use to exchange a subset of your entity between different application layers

Comment: ,Then will sql query  look like Select new package.myDTO(field,..) from Enquiry enquiry where ( enquiry.* = input value, enquiry.issue.* = input value).Can this stop fetching too many entities?

Comment: In this way you can limit the number of fetched columns. To limit results you can use setFirstResult / setMaxResults

Comment: Hi,We have already implemented the setFirstResult/setmaxResults.

Comment: Hi,Is it possible that using new dtopackege.myDto(field, field, field) will fetch the fields decalred in the query?

Comment: @SudheerKumarS I have updated my answer! Hope now it's more clear!

Comment: I have been trying your second solution.I will let you about it once it is done.

Comment: @SudheerKumarS Ok. Here you can find some docs: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select

Comment: Hello,Thank you for sharing this article and I am going thorough it.I will implement that.

Comment: ,Thank your for suggesting new constructor query.We have implemented in lot of places in our applications and it gave very very very best results.Thank you very much!!